# pull first matching row from sql group

Tags: sql, group-by, ansi-sql

Say you have a projection like the following:

```
Artist         Painting            Year
---------------------------------------
Alfred         Birds               1945
Alfred         Apples&Oranges      1947
Ben            ZealousNeighbours   1912
Calum          Hope Spliced        1760
Calum          Horseplay           1765
Calum          Earth               1780
David          Apples&Oranges      1947
```

How do I return the first following relation:

```
Artist         Painting            Year
---------------------------------------
Alfred         Birds               1945
Ben            ZealousNeighbours   1912
Calum          Hope Spliced        1760
David          Apples&Oranges      1947
```

i.e the first painting each painter painted..

**ANSI SQL only**

Comment: What should happen where there are two paintings for the same year?

Comment: of those two, return the first alphabetically, though it's not stipulated

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
SELECT
    [Artist],
    [Painting],
    [Year]
FROM
(
    SELECT
        [Artist],
        [Painting],
        [Year],
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Artist] ORDER BY [Year] ASC) AS [Rank]
    FROM
        [Table]
) AS a
WHERE
    a.[Rank] = 1
```

Comment: @egrunin brings up a valid question. You could add a secondary order by in the `Rank` determination above. Example: `ORDER BY [Year] ASC, [Painting] ASC`

Comment: What I would have posted, verbatim. +1

Answer (score 0):

This should work on any ANSI-89 compliant SQL dialect, however it will break if an artist did multiple paintings in their first year - you could tweak this by storing an actual datetime value instead of just the year if you need finer granularity.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Paintings 
    INNER JOIN
    (SELECT Artist, MIN([Year]) MinYear 
     FROM Paintings 
     GROUP BY Artist) 
    Minimum ON Minimum.MinYear = Paintings.Year AND Minimum.Artist = Paintings.Artist
```

If your SQL is ANSI-2003 compliant you can do what diaho listed above.

e: I don't think there's a way to guarantee only returning one row per artist using ANSI-89 SQL only.

Comment: The problem is the query I've created to form that relation. I need to go back to the drawing board on this, thanks for the answer though.